# iAd always showing at bottom of view controller

Tags: view, uinavigationcontroller, iad, tabbar

I am trying to have my bannerad show at the top of my view controller above my tableview which is also in my view controller. Additionally, I'm using navigation controller and tab bar controller. When the ad becomes available, I want the ad to slide from the top and push my tableview down by the height of the banner ad (50px). I've had a heck of a time doing this! I've tried a ton of different tutorials and techniques and i can't get any to work like i want.

At this, point, I am just trying to load the ad at the top and I have very simple code but it is always at the bottom behind the tab bar no matter what i do. any assistance to accomplish my object is GREATLY appreciated! Additionally, if i drag bannerad object from storyboard, above my tableview controller, then that works, but I'm left with white space when no ad loads. So, i think i have to do this programmatically but struggling here.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:adView];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out so am posting my answer in case anyone needed it:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    //Moves tableview down when banner becomes available
    m_tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,464);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    NSLog(@"Got Banner");
}
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
if (self.bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    //Moves tableview back up when banner is unavailable
    m_tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,504);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"Got NO Banner");
}
}
```